# Object enclosed by parentheses

Tags: java

I'm learning data structures and encountered the code below. I'm really curious about the meaning of parentheses around `new Object();`.

```
public class HashTable <K,V> implements Iterable<K> {
    private final K TOMBSTONE=(K) (new Object());
}
```

I assume the parentheses around K are for down casting that makes the `new Object();` be of data type `K`.
What are the parentheses around `new Object();` for?

Could you please tell me in plain English?

Comment: I was incorrect to say at first that it is required in this context. However it can be required in some contexts for precedence of operations. See [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/expressions.html). But yea most of the time it's used to aid with legibility even if it isn't required.

Comment: In this situation it doesn't really make a difference to legibility so removing it is perfectly fine.

Answer (score 4):

The parentheses aren't functionally required. They're just there for readability. It would compile without them:

```
public class HashTable <K,V> implements Iterable<K> {
    private final K TOMBSTONE=(K) new Object();
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your natural editing and prompt response that gets to the point. It is really helpful because I'm learning alone on youtube, there are plenty of things that drive me nuts.